# Unpermitted parameter: :phone_number. Context: { controller: OrdersController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007f54ac186660>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

I created a form with custom routing for orders with `resources :orders , only: [:new, :create]` and i want the users to click the submit button and the form fields should save the data into database, but when i click submit button, inside of the terminal it shows `unpermitted params` can anyone point out the mistake what i am doing in order for it to save into database

> orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    # GET to /orders/new
    def new
        @order = Order.new
    end

    # POST to /orders
    def create
        @order = Order.new(order_params)
        if @order.save
            redirect_to root_path, notice: "Order saved"
            
        else
            redirect_to root_path, notice: "Error Occured"
        end



    end

    private
        def order_params
            params.require(:order).permit(:paper_size, :color, :quantity, :type, :description, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_numnber, :email, files: [] )
        end
end
```

> order.rb (MODEL)

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :admin

    validates :paper_size, presence: true
    validates :color, presence: true
    validates :quantity, presence: true
    validates :type, presence: true
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :phone_number, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true

   

    has_many_attached :files


end
```

> orders/new.html.erb (VIEWS)

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Order From Home!</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            
            <%= f.label :first_name%>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, class:"form-control" %><br/>

            <%= f.label :last_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, class:"form-control" %><br/>
           

            <%= f.label :phone_number %>
            <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class:"form-control" %><br/>

           
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email, class:"form-control" %><br/>

            <%= f.label :files %>
            <%= f.file_field :files, multiple: true %><br/>
          

            <%= f.label :paper_size %>
             <%= f.select :paper_size, ['A4', 'B4'], { prompt: 'Select' }, class:'form-select' %><br/>

            <%= f.label :color %>
            <%= f.select :color, ['Black & White', 'Color'], { prompt: 'Select' }, class:'form-select' %><br/>

            <%= f.label :quantity %>
            <%= f.select :quantity, options_for_select(0..500), { prompt: "Select" }, class:'form-select' %><br/>

            <%= f.label :description %>
            <%= f.text_area :description, class:"form-control" %><br/>

            <div class="btn-order">
                <%= f.submit %>
            </div>
           
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

> routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
  devise_scope :admin do
    get '/admins/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
  root 'pages#home'
  get '/about', to: 'pages#about'

  resources :orders , only: [:new, :create]


  resources :admins, only: [:index]
end
```

Comment: There is a typo in phone_numnber in the order_params method.

Comment: waww i was thinking for hours what did i do wrong! xD Thanks slot

Answer (score 1):

You typed `phone_numnber`, not `phone_number`.

Comment: oh shiiish thankss my bad xD